# PHP Currency display

Tags: php, forms, echo, currency

I am trying to display a £ sign and commas with in a number to show currency but i'm not sure how to, here is the code i have that echo's it as 8999999 instead of £8,999,999

```
<div id="form">
<form action="index.php" method="post">

   <center> <input type="text" name="percent" id="percent" />
  <input type="submit"  /> </center>

</form>
<center> 
<?php
    $percent=$_POST['percent'];
    $total = 8999999;

    /*calculation for discounted price */ 

    $discount_value=$total/100*$percent;

    $final_price = $total - $discount_value;

    echo $final_price;

?> 
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: [number_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or [money_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) or [sprint()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [basic php form help (currency display)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345704/basic-php-form-help-currency-display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have a look at number_format (http://php.net/manual/de/function.number-format.php)

```
echo '&pound;'.number_format($final_price, 0);
```

results in £8,999,999

```
echo '&pound;'.number_format($final_price, 2);
```

results in £8,999,999.00

Answer (score 1):

You can use money_format function. As you can see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php you can format number in *your* currency:

```
// let's print the international format for the en_US locale
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
// USD 1,234.56
```

Answer (score 0):

try `echo '£'.number_format($final_price,2,",",".");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$amount = '100000';
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');
utf8_encode(money_format('%n', $amount));
```

refer this

http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

```
<?php
    echo "&pound".money_format('%.2n', $final_price);
?>
```

Check the money_format on php.net

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this and let me know if you still have questions.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you were looking for:

> echo '£' . number_format($final_price);